# Doctrine constraints: is the custom validator implemented in JavaScript too?

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

I've made my own Form class in the file `src/HQF/Bundle/PizzasBundle/Form/Type/VilleType.php`

It's really short:

```
<?php

namespace HQF\Bundle\PizzasBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class VilleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {   
        $builder->add('cp', 'text', array('max_length' => 5));
    }
    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {   
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'HQF\Bundle\PizzasBundle\Entity\Ville',
        );
    }
    public function getName()
    {   
        return 'ville';
    }
}
```

Now I've made my validator in the file `src/HQF/Bundle/PizzasBundle/Validator/Constraints/FrenchPostalCodeValidator.php`. It works, so, to make it short, here's the code of the validator class:

```
<?php

namespace HQF\Bundle\PizzasBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class FrenchPostalCodeValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {   
        if (!preg_match('/^([0-9]{5}|2[A|B])$/', $value, $matches)) {
            $this->context->addViolation(
                $constraint->message,
                array('%string%' => $value)
            );  
        }   
    }   
}
```

This is just a simple Regexp. When, in the Form, I say `array('max_length' => 5)` then there's some JavaScript validation added on the client side. This is nice. is there a way to add custom validators so they're added on the client side too. I guess something like `array('max_length' => 5, 'FrenchPostalCode')` or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in JavaScript validation in Symfony2. What you're talking about is [HTML5 form validation](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-maxlength-attribute) that's supported directly by browsers — no JavaScript involved.

There is the [`pattern` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) you could try to use to implement the validation you need. If it doesn't solve the problem, you'll have to use JavaScript.